# Vue2. How to use v-html in JSX

Tags: vuejs2

I have quite a short question.

How to use `v-html` directive in vue JSX syntax?

Thanks in advance for an answer.

Comment: You're looking for [`domProps.innerHTML`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`domPropsInnerHTML`](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx#difference-from-react-jsx) (one word, exactly like this, see below).

Example:

```html
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Something foo bar'
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <h1 domPropsInnerHTML={this.msg}></h1>
    );
  }
};
```

[**CodeSandbox demo here.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/xlonl3mwv4?module=%2FApp.js)

Comment: Did you get try it out?

Comment: yes! Sorry, was badly ill. I tried it, it works fine. Thank you much!